# turning data stored in document properties back to an array and push to range; GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get data from Document Properties, turn it into an array, and push it to a sheet. The sheet happens to be in a different spreadsheet than the one where the script is, but I've already got that worked out.
The problem I'm having is in converting the data in properties into a 2D array [{userID, sheetName}, {anotherUser, anotherSheet}]. 
*There are currently five sets of user data in Properties, based on a separate function created to test my data.
*Array length of the pairsArray returns one item, presumably the whole data set.
*Array length of useStatsPairs (all the data in Properties) returns 295, which I'm guessing is characters.

In a previous version of this script I was pulling the data from a hidden sheet in the same workbook. A member of this forum reminded me that DocumentProperties was a better way to go.

```
function storeStats(sheetTitle) {
var docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var userID = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 
var thisData = [];
thisData.push(userID, sheetTitle);
var thisDataStr = JSON.stringify(thisData);
docProps.setProperty('USEDATA', docProps.getProperty('USEDATA') + 
","+thisDataStr);

sendStats();
}

function sendStats() {
//vars for properties
var pairsArray = [];
var docProps = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
var stringPairs= JSON.stringify(docProps.getProperty('USEDATA'));
var useStatsPairs = JSON.parse(stringPairs);
pairsArray.push(useStatsPairs);
Logger.log(pairsArray.length);

//vars for remote sheet
var useLogHome = "1tKISbjHIS8m7HMNRE7ygTOl1s5PsvU3FDF6BEDoVtDw";
var logDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(useLogHome);
var logSheet = logDoc.getSheetByName("Collect");
var lastRemoteRow = logSheet.getLastRow();
var newLogCell = lastRemoteRow+1;
var startRemoteRg = logSheet.getRange(newLogCell,1);
Logger.log(startRemoteRg.getValues());

//now send the properties to an array
//startRemoteRg.setValues(pairsArray);
Logger.log(pairsArray.length);
Logger.log("values in props: "+pairsArray);
}
```

Script edited to most current version. Data returned using a test function is as follows: 
[19-07-13 21:01:11:051 PDT] null,["bulletinator@gmail.com","Script 07/03/2019"],["bulletinator@gmail.com","Script 07/12/2019"]

Ultimately this function should pull data from Document Properties, create an array, then populate the remote sheet with email addresses in column 1 and sheet name in column 2.

Edit and solution
I decided to simplify my approach. My previous desire, based on another stackOverflow member, was about gathering data each time the user runs one of the functions and sending once a certain amount of data was present. Since that has proved to be too complex for now, I'm sending data on each use. I understand quota may be an issue, but at this point I have only 90 users running the program a few times a day at most. In light of that, I've decided to run the following code, similar to what @cooper suggests:

```
function storeStats(sheetTitle) {
var userID = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); 

//remote data collection spreadsheet
var useLogHome = "999";  //spreadsheet reference number
var logDoc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(useLogHome);
var logSheet = logDoc.getSheetByName("Collect");
var lastRemoteRow = logSheet.getLastRow()+1;

var idRg = logSheet.getRange(lastRemoteRow,1);
var shtRg = logSheet.getRange(lastRemoteRow,2);

idRg.setValue(userID);
shtRg.setValue(sheetTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function collects data from Sheet172 and stores it into USEDATA in PropertiesService with `JSON.stringify(vA)`. It then takes it out and recreates the 2D array with `JSON.parse(ps.getProperty("USEDATA"));` and using setValues() it populates Sheet173.

So it might be simpler just to store it as a stringified array.

```
function collectData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet172');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  ps.setProperty("USEDATA",JSON.stringify(vA));
  Logger.log(ps.getProperty("USEDATA"));
  var vB=JSON.parse(ps.getProperty("USEDATA"));
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet173');
  osh.clearContents()
  osh.getRange(1,1,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}
```

This is my Sheet172:

[image]

Comment: In this cast you have pulled the data from another sheet. In my storeStats function the sheet title is passed from a previous function, and the userID is generated within. I don't think the problem is in passing the information to Properties as a string, since I've got that in my storeStats function, but in extracting it properly. I could also be amiss in how I'm passing the data to the USEDATA property, but our approach at that end is different. Again, I'm trying to avoid using a sheet to pass the data from.

Comment: You don't have to put into a sheet but you might as well put it into the form that you want when it's outputted.  So try this declare thisData as array `var thisData = [];` and then when you save each pair just use thisData.push([userID,sheetTitle]);`

Comment: I like the array method because I understand arrays and loops. when I use the method you point out I get the following when I Log Properties contents: [19-07-13 20:55:25:626 PDT] null,[["bulletinator@gmail.com","Script 07/12/2019"]],[["bulletinator@gmail.com","Script 07/03/2019"]]  This does not look like the objects are inside the same array due to double brackets around both.

Comment: The line of code var vB=JSON.parse(docProps.getProperty("USEDATA")); is causing an error: "Expected end of stream at char 4 (line 19...)...  This problem does not occur if I change it to var vB=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docProps.getProperty("USEDATA")));